# Can a parent class create an instance of its subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, sonarqube

I ran unit tests with Sonarqube on some Java code and one of the issues I found is the following.

> Classes should not access their own subclasses during initialization

> When a parent class references a member of a subclass during its own initialization, the results might not be what you expect because the child class might not have been initialized yet. This could create what is known as an "initialisation cycle", or even a deadlock in some extreme cases.

This is the example code that Sonarqube used to describe the issue:

```
class Parent {
  static int field1 = Child.method(); // Noncompliant
  static int field2 = 42;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Parent.field1); // will display "0" instead of "42"
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  static int method() {
    return Parent.field2;
  }
}
```

Next is a simplification of the code that raised the issue.

```
abstract class Parent {
    static Parent childInstance = new Child();
}
```

I don't really understand why this is an issue. In the Sonarqube example, the parent is initializing `field1` by calling the static method of the child. This means that I don't need to instantiate a child before calling the method.

In the second snippet of code, the parent is trying to instantiate the child rather than calling one of its methods.

Can you please explain to me why it's not possible to refer to the child in the parent class?

EDIT: I'm using SonarScanner for Maven and my Sonarqube version is 8.4.1.35646. The rule id of the issue is S2390.

Comment: What is the sonarqube version? Also, can you share the rule-id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about when code is executed here:

```
abstract class Parent {
    static Parent childInstance = new Child();
}
```

Since your assigning to a `static` field the `new Child()` has to be executed long before the first `Parent` instance is created.

Namely during class initialization (for simplicities sake, let's assume that's equivalent to "class loading", even though that's not quite accurate).

That means that while the class `Parent` is being initialized it creates a new instance of `Child`. Usually one of the first thing that needs to happen for initialization to complete is that the super class is already initialized. Since we're currently initializing `Parent` we can know that `Child` can't already be fully initialized (by definition, since that would require `Parent` to be fully initialized).

There are some "tricks" that the JVM/Java language spec plays to actually allow this construct to work, but they have drawbacks (such as being able to observe uninitialized `final` fields).

Think of it that way: you are trying to grab something from the second story of a house while you're busy building the basement.